# difference between the two greatest numbers with increasing digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the difference between highest ever increasing number and second highest ever increasing number? (eg. 19,12345,189..etc)

My approach 
Highest ever increasing number will be 123456789,
and the second highest number like this will be 012345678

Hence, their difference is 123456789 - 012345678 = 111111111.

but dont know i m right or wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "highest ever increasing number"?

Comment: highest ever increasing number means -->1,12,123 this way

Answer (score 0):

The greatest is of course 123,456,789.  The next-greatest can then be at most 8 digits long, so let's use the 8 largest digits in order, namely 23,456,789.